# How to convert "Mon Mar 14 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)" into 2014-03-08 using Moment.js

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

In AngularJS i.e in controller.js file I am retrieving the date from database in this format i.e "Mon Mar 14 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)". But when I display this date using AngularJS datepicker on html page it is showing empty means it is not showing the date with this format i.e 2014-03-08.

Answer (score 1):

Here's example on how to convert date format using moment js

```
<div id="date"></div>
<div id="momentdate"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var d = new Date();   //Sat Mar 05 2016 17:48:48 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
    $('#date').text(d);
    var md = moment(d).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    $('#momentdate').text(md);
});
</script>
```

output

```
Sat Mar 05 2016 17:48:48 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
2016-03-05
```

working example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samshameem/2xofg1tn/)

Comment: But .text() is not supported in angularjs controllers

Comment: to display the result i have made use of that. The date format you require `moment(d).format('YYYY-MM-DD');`